# Cannot find name 'process' error when building NestJS for production after downgrading to typeorm@0.2

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs, yarnpkg, typeorm

After reading the docs on NestJS regarding using TypeORM for database management, it was recommended to use `typeorm@0.2` because the latest version of `typeorm` library has substantial changes that is not compatible with the current `@nestjs/typeorm` mentioned [here](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/database). But after doing so, I have received an error below:

```
Cannot find name 'process'. Do you need to install type definitions for node? Try `npm i --save-dev @types/node`.
```

You can check the error from GitHub action job [here](https://github.com/dominicarrojado/nestjs-postgres-boilerplate/runs/6224253202?check_suite_focus=true) as well.

Do note that if I didn't do the downgrade, I will not receive the error mentioned above. I could also install `@types/node` as a dependency instead of devDependency but I felt that's hacking it instead of solving it. If I build for production, I shouldn't need the types at all. Is there any other way around this?

[Here's the link](https://github.com/dominicarrojado/nestjs-postgres-boilerplate) to the repository if you need to check the configs.

Thank you in advance.